# How to add an unauthenticated check to the handler in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I modified app/Exceptions/Handler.php to have an unauthenticated function. Since it's purely an API I am only returning json.

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated'], 401);
}
```

After adding that `php artisan tinker` gives me the following error.

```
[ErrorException]
  Declaration of App\Exceptions\Handler::unauthenticated($request, App\Exceptions\AuthenticationException $exception) should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler::unauthenticated($request, Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException $exception)
```

But I'm not sure what needs to change in order for it to be compatible.  I idi add a use statement `use Illuminate\Auth\AuthentificationException;` to the top of the handler.

Answer (score 1):

you should use Exception and request too

be sure you include like this:

```
namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Response;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
```

and your method should be like this:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest('/');
}
```

your code just response as json